# Can we add the same namespace for two javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-namespaces

I am trying to put all my javascript function in one namespace. I have two javascript files and i am trying to put all the functions both the files into one namespace. So when i define the same namespace for both the files. The first gets over written by the second. I have defined my namespace in both the files as shown below. Is there a way i can stop this other putting all the function to one file? Thanks for the help.

```
var mynamespace={
foo:function(){Som code},
bar:function(){some code}
};
```

Comment: There's also RequireJS and AMD. I think I saw a [nanoloader](https://gist.github.com/pradador/218423) in JS the other day too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  In each file:

```
var mynamespace = mynamespace || {};
```

And then pick the next line for the file you have:

```
mynamespace.foo = function () {
```

or

```
mynamespace.bar = function () {
```

Basically, what this does is assign a current value of `mynamespace` to `mynamespace` if it exists.  Otherwise, it creates a new object.  Note that depending on if you declare `mynamespace` above or not, you might need this line up top instead:

```
if (typeof mynamespace === 'undefined') { var mynamespace = {} }
```

Comment: I wish PHP supported `this || that` syntax.